# Java 8 with HttpClient 4.3.5 unable to connect to Https with Proxy

Tags: java, http, https, java-8, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have this code

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.config.RegistryBuilder;
import org.apache.http.conn.socket.ConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.URI;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class ConnectToHttpsSafelyTest {

    @Test
    public void httpAndHttpsWithProxyTest() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(executeHttpCall("http://myexternalip.com/raw"));
        System.out.println(executeHttpCall("https://myexternalip.com/raw"));
    }


    private Object executeHttpCall(final String url) throws Exception{
        final SSLContextBuilder sslBuilder = new SSLContextBuilder();
        sslBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(null,(chain,authType)->true);
        final HttpClientBuilder httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        setUpProxy(httpClient,sslBuilder);
        final HttpRequestBase request = new HttpGet();
        ((HttpGet) request).setURI(URI.create(url));
        final Object obj = httpClient.build().execute(request, new BasicResponseHandler(), HttpClientContext.create());
        return obj;
    }


    private void setUpProxy(HttpClientBuilder builder, SSLContextBuilder sslBuilder)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        final SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory =
                new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslBuilder.build(), new String[]{"SSLv2Hello", "SSLv3", "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"}, null, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

        Authenticator.setDefault(null);
        HttpHost httpProxy = new HttpHost("proxyHost", proxyPort, "http");
        CredentialsProvider cred_provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        cred_provider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(httpProxy), new UsernamePasswordCredentials("proxyUser", "proxyPassword"));

        final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager conn_mgr
                = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(RegistryBuilder.
                <ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
                .register("https", sslConnectionSocketFactory)
                .build());
        conn_mgr.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        conn_mgr.setMaxTotal(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        builder.setConnectionManager(conn_mgr)
                .setProxy(httpProxy)
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(cred_provider);
        builder.setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory);
    }
}
```

But i received

```
220.1.72.193

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error

    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2038)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1135)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.upgrade(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:193)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.upgrade(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:389)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:416)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:221)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:165)
```

As you can see I am getting the IP able to connect to the website using just HTTP but not using Https even when I try to ignore every validation.

I'm not good on HttpClient. How can I resolve this?

```
Using Java 8 build 181
Apache Client 4.3.5
```

Also fails with Java 19:

[image: Java 19 fails]

Comment: Java 8 181 is nearly 5 years old. Have you considered to use a more recent version of Java 8? Also make sure the proxy is a recent version to have modern TLS versions available.

Comment: Trying to solve 'internal error' in the server from the client is like flying at night without instruments, almost certain to fail. I would first check if the proxy logs any relevant information. But if I had to fly blind I'd start by removing SSLv2Hello; that's been useless or harmful for two decades, and defaulted off in JSSE client since j7 in 2011. (SSLv3 is also useless, but not harmful because all Java 8u31 up automatically ignore it.) Also a connection that doesn't verify hostid wouldn't be 'Safe[]'.

Comment: @Robert Also failing with Java 19

Comment: Please do not post terminal output as screen shot. Just copy and paste the full text, paste it into your question and format it as code. If the used server is accessible from Internet I would recommend to perform an ssl test https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Men it worked can you please provide the answer to mark as solved.